# Firebase DNS A records with GoDaddy? SSL error: "Your connection is not private"

Tags: firebase, ssl, dns

Chrome displays this error message when I go to my web app:

[image]

My Firebase console shows that my domain is connected:

[image]

My GoDaddy domain manager console shows these records:

[image]

The TXT record shows that Google site verification is complete. My guess is the problem is that the DNS A records are pointing to the wrong values, but I can't find the correct DNS A records in my Firebase console. Any suggestions?

Comment: Thomas, did you find a solution for this problem? I have tried several suggestions from Firebase support and none of them worked so far, bringing the website down each time.